# VBA in Excel assigns a value to a cell, but that is not the value shown in the cell after code is run

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote VBA code that reads through a simple text file containing comma separated values and assigns these values to an array.  Each array value then gets assigned to a cell on an Excel worksheet.  Relevant lines of code are as follows:

```
Dim arySingle(826) As Single

Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input Form")

... various lines of code...

sht.Range("STLI").Value = arySingle(654)

... code continues on...
```

Note:  "Input Form" is the only worksheet in the workbook.

The value read in from the text file is .06.  I have verified this both by looking at the text file contents and by breaking the code on the VBA line above and tested the value of `arySingle(654)` in the Immediate window.  No other line of code affects the named range "STLI".

The named range (single cell) "STLI" is formatted as a two decimal percentage cell.  After the VBA code runs, the cell shows 6.00%, but when selected, it shows a value of 5.99999986588954% in the formula bar.  I do have other cells similarly formatted, and when a value is passed to them, they also show a value other than the value passed by the VBA code.

What would be causing this?  What is the solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try rounding your value? Can we see the rest of the code and see how things are being handled?

Comment: You're up against a well known numeric precision discussion with rounding errors. [This article in Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel) gives a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel, and to an extension VBA, does not have the precision that programming languages such as Java or C# have.  Excel has a precision limit of 15 significant figures. You are using the `Single` data type, which is considered a floating point value.

This is a good read about floating point precisions in Excel: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/

Comment: Your comment and the link you provided seems to have answered my question, thank you.  By turning on "Precision as Displayed", as described in the link, my cell now shows 6% on the formula bar and 6.00% on the screen, as it should.